# What conditions for the diagonal matrix $\mathbf{D}$ satisfying $\operatorname{rank}([DA,A]) = 2n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Given a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}(m > n)$ with $\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A}) = n$. What conditions the diagonal matrix D satisfies
$\operatorname{rank}([\mathbf{DA,A}]) = 2\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A})$?

Since 
\begin{equation}
   \begin{pmatrix}
        \mathbf{A}^{-1}_{\text{left}}\mathbf{D}^{-1}\\
        \mathbf{A}^{-1}_{\text{left}}
   \end{pmatrix}
   [\mathbf{DA,A}]=
   \begin{pmatrix}
        \mathbf{I}_{n} & \mathbf{0}\\
        \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I}_{n}
   \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{A}^{-1}_{\text{left}}$ is Left inverse of $\mathbf{A}$, so the condition for $\mathbf{D}$ which defined by
\begin{equation}
   \begin{cases}
        \mathbf{A}^{-1}_{\text{left}}\mathbf{D}^{-1} \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{0} \\
        \mathbf{A}^{-1}_{\text{left}}\mathbf{DA} = \mathbf{0}
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Is this all right? If not, what the other condition for $\mathbf{D}$?

Answer (score 1):

No. If $[DA,A]$ has full rank, we do have
$$
\pmatrix{XD^{-1}\\ Y}[DA,A]=\pmatrix{I_n\\ &I_n}
$$
for *some* left inverses $X$ and $Y$ of $A$, but $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily equal. E.g. consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{1\\ 1},\ D=\pmatrix{2\\ &1},\ [DA,A]^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ -1&2}=\pmatrix{XD^{-1}\\ Y}
$$
where $X=(2,-1)\ne(-1,2)=Y$.

Provided that $A$ is a real tall matrix of full column rank, here are two necessary and sufficient conditions for $[DA,A]$ to have full column rank:

1. $\det([DA,A]^T[DA,A])>0$.
2. $\operatorname{rank}((I - AA^+)DA)=n$, or equivalently, $\det(A^TD(I - AA^+)DA)>0$. Its connection to the previous condition is that $A^TD(I - AA^+)DA$ is the Schur complement of $A^TA$ in $[DA,A]^T[DA,A]$.